# Android - What´s the difference between WifiManager disableNetwork() and disconnect()

Tags: android, wifimanager

What´s the main difference between the WifiManager `disableNetwork()` and `disconnect()` method?

If I´m not guessing wrong, the `disconnect()` method makes it candidate for a reconnect when it enters inside the visibility of the wifi hotspot but `disableNetwork()` don't.

> **public boolean disableNetwork (int netId)**. Disable a configured network. The specified network will not be a candidate for
>   associating. This may result in the asynchronous delivery of state
>   change events.
>
> **public boolean disconnect ()** Disassociate from the currently active access point. This may result in the asynchronous delivery of
>   state change events.

I´ve a Wiko Darkmoon (Android 4.2.2) device for testing purposes and when I call `disconnect()` it reconnects some seconds later to the same wifi point without taking in mind higher priority networks neither the quality of the signal.

So my questions are:

- What's the difference between `disableNetwork()` and `disconnect()` method?
- It´s my guess right?
- It´s the Wiko's implementation the right one or it´s the one misfiring?
- When roaming between two wifi spots with same SSID and after calling `disconnect()` will it filter by SSID or MAC for the reconnect?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`disconnect()` as name suggests just disconnects the device from current Wi-Fi network. If the device connects later to the same or another network is dependent on the device settings and is completely unrelated to the method call.

`disableNetwork(int)` will prevent automatic connection to the specified network.

Comment: I don't know how to put this clear, but I´ll try. If I have 2 spots with the same SSID and call disconnect, then move to the second spot will it connect even thought they have the same SSID or it will filter them by MAC?

Comment: This should have been you original question. I've read about devices preferring the original hotpot despite there being a stronger AP with same SSID (so you call `disconnect()`, move and it will reconnect to the original hotspot). I can't back this up with a source though so please disregard this answer.

Comment: @EugenPeachec I had 3 questions and you sholved pretty much all of them, so thanks. I will wait some time to get more answers and then accept one.

Comment: No problem. I suggest you add the question about roaming between two APs with same SSID to the list in OP, so people know what exact problem are you trying to solve right away.